# Failed to load resource the server responded with a status of 404

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, wordpress

Hi i have this error in Chrome console: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost/wordpress/add_likes.php

js source

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

js code is

```
function addLikes(id,action) {
    $('.demo-table #tutorial-'+id+' li').each(function(index) {
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        $('#tutorial-'+id+' #rating').val((index+1));
        if(index == $('.demo-table #tutorial-'+id+' li').index(obj)) {
            return false;   
        }
    });
     $.ajax({
    url: 'add_likes.php',
    data:'id='+id+'&action='+action,
    type: "POST",
    beforeSend: function(){
        $('#tutorial-'+id+' .btn-likes').html("<img src='http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/loaderIcon.gif' />");
    },
    success: function(data){
    var likes = parseInt($('#likes-'+id).val());
    switch(action) {
        case "like":
        $('#tutorial-'+id+' .btn-likes').html('<input type="button" title="Unlike" class="unlike" onClick="addLikes('+id+',\'unlike\')" />');
        likes = likes+1;
        break;
        case "unlike":
        $('#tutorial-'+id+' .btn-likes').html('<input type="button" title="Like" class="like"  onClick="addLikes('+id+',\'like\')" />')
        likes = likes-1;
        break;
    }
    $('#likes-'+id).val(likes);
    if(likes>0) {
        $('#tutorial-'+id+' .label-likes').html(likes+" Like(s)");
    } else {
        $('#tutorial-'+id+' .label-likes').html('');
    }
    }
    });
}
```

and, yeah im using wordpress.

i Hope some one can help me :(

Comment: Is file present in your wordpress root folder?

Comment: This file is in the same folder as index.

Comment: Ou, my b :D now it work's, thx :)
But now it didn't make like + 1 or like -1, what it could be? :(

Comment: again,my b, solved :D Thx :)